# Where NavigationProperty.date >= Date, returns empty list even though database has valid data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following to objects:

```
public class DeviceTests
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? EnvironmentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Common.Environment Environment { get; set; } 
//.. other prop's
}

public class Environment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Computer { get; set; }
    public string OSVer { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to get an IQueryable back that, when processed, will produce a set of DeviceTests objects where their Environment object has a time stamp in the given range. There is 1-to-1 relationship between the two objects (tables).

so far have tried the following with out success:

```
var allTests = context.DeviceTests.Where(x =>
                x.Environment.TimeStamp >= searchTime && 
                x.Environment.TimeStamp <= endTime).ToList();
```

returns: []. (should be 8 given the dates provided)

```
var evs = context.Environment.Where(x =>
                    x.TimeStamp >= searchTime && 
                    x.TimeStamp <= endTime).Select(x=> x.Id).ToList();
var allTests = context.DeviceTests.Where(x =>
                evs.Containes(x.EnvironmentId)).ToList();
```

evs returns 8 correct environment ids.
all Tests returns empty list.

```
var allTests = context.DeviceTests.Include(x=> x.Environment).Where(x =>
                x.Environment.TimeStamp >= searchTime && 
                x.Environment.TimeStamp <= endTime).ToList();
```

returns: []. (should be 8 given the dates provided)

I even tried this to see if I can get one back DeviceTest back

```
var evs = context.Environment.Where(x =>
          x.TimeStamp >= searchTime && 
          x.TimeStamp <= endTime).Select(x=> x.Id).ToList();
int temp = evs[0];    
var allTests = context.DeviceTests.Where(x =>
          x.EnvironmentId == temp).ToList();
```

but still got 8 correct environment ids in evs, and allTests returns empty list.

The database was set up using EF code first. The code is being executed by a service that is used by an API controller.

**Addition**

I am now considering that I approaching this problem from the wrong angle. With out resorting to writing straight SQL, How would you solve this problem? Where you have the above mentioned objects in a code first db and you need to get out a collection of DeviceTests based on a time stamp stored in the environment object. Open to any suggestions.

**Update**

I have made a small mini project to replicate my issue. The problem is my mini project does not replicate my issue and works correctly. So I don't think this is an issue with the linq query I think the issues is now somewhere else. Any pointers of areas to look would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to make sure, if you use `context.DeviceTests.ToList()`, do you get anything at all?

Comment: yep get the whole Table all 2000 + records

Comment: What if you use `context.DeviceTests.ToList().Where(...)`?

Comment: pls check the date/time format is correct. To confirm that select data with  any other condition instead of the date/time

Comment: the date/time variable are DateTime typed object that are correctly parsed as I have do some date mathematics to get the endTime based on the given search time.

Comment: @LibinCJacob That doesn't really matter since they are `DateTime` objects and not strings

Comment: when I tried `var test = _allDeviceTests.ToList().Where(x => x.EnvironmentId == 1);` I got a List iterator with a current property set to null. _allDevicesTests is just a short hand variable for context.DeviceTests

Comment: Which EF?  We have Core and non-Core in several versions now. And LazyLoading is one of the major differences.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, non-core ver: 6 (according to properties of my ef reference)

Comment: And what is your lazy setting?

Comment: @HenkHolterman, default I believe. How would I double check to help you?

Answer (score 0):

Can't really test it without your data, but this looks like it might do the job:

```
var allTests =
    from deviceTest in context.DeviceTests
    where deviceTest.EnvironmentId.HasValue
    let environment = deviceTest.Environment
    where environment.TimeStamp <= endTime &&
          environment.TimeStamp >= searchTime
    select deviceTest;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but when I just tried it I just got back all of the data from the deviceTest table.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone who has offered their help. I have found the solution so am posting it for anyone who needs this help in the future.

TL;DR - the answer is :

```
var allTests = context.DeviceTests
    .Where(x =>x.Environment.TimeStamp >= searchTime)
    .Where(x =>x.Environment.TimeStamp <= endTime)
    .ToList();
```

For others who are still learning how to solve issues like this, below shows my process with code.

To get to this solution I created a mini project and included only the most basic and vital code, the project was uncreatively called Linq_Issues:

```
public class Environment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Computer { get; set; }
    public string OSVer { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }

}

public class DeviceTest
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Environment Env {get; set;}
}

public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public TestContext() : base("name=Testing")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Linq_Issues.Environment> Envs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DeviceTest> DeviceTests { get; set; }
}
```

I then created a new code first database and used the following configuration in the migration.

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Linq_Issues.TestContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(Linq_Issues.TestContext context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data.

        context.DeviceTests.AddOrUpdate(new DeviceTest
        {
            Env = new Linq_Issues.Environment
            {
                Computer = "1",
                OSVer = "Win",
                User = "Test",
                Version = "1",
                TimeStamp = new DateTime(2018, 1, 22)
            }
        });
        context.DeviceTests.AddOrUpdate(new DeviceTest
        {
            Env = new Linq_Issues.Environment
            {
                Computer = "2",
                OSVer = "Linux",
                User = "Ted",
                Version = "1",
                TimeStamp = new DateTime(2018, 1, 23)
            }
        }); context.DeviceTests.AddOrUpdate(new DeviceTest
        {
            Env = new Linq_Issues.Environment
            {
                Computer = "1",
                OSVer = "Win",
                User = "Bill",
                Version = "1",
                TimeStamp = new DateTime(2018, 1, 24)
            }
        }); context.DeviceTests.AddOrUpdate(new DeviceTest
        {
            Env = new Linq_Issues.Environment
            {
                Computer = "1",
                OSVer = "Win",
                User = "Ted",
                Version = "1",
                TimeStamp = new DateTime(2018, 1, 25)
            }
        }); context.DeviceTests.AddOrUpdate(new DeviceTest
        {
            Env = new Linq_Issues.Environment
            {
                Computer = "2",
                OSVer = "Linux",
                User = "Bill",
                Version = "1",
                TimeStamp = new DateTime(2018, 1, 26)
            }
        }); context.DeviceTests.AddOrUpdate(new DeviceTest
        {
            Env = new Linq_Issues.Environment
            {
                Computer = "2",
                OSVer = "Linux",
                User = "Bill",
                Version = "1",
                TimeStamp = new DateTime(2018, 1, 28)
            }
        }); context.DeviceTests.AddOrUpdate(new DeviceTest
        {
            Env = new Linq_Issues.Environment
            {
                Computer = "2",
                OSVer = "Linux",
                User = "Jill",
                Version = "1",
                TimeStamp = new DateTime(2018, 1, 31)
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I was then free to start experimenting. I broke down what I wanted to achieve into the smallest chunks I could think of. That started with getting a Linq to just compare an exact date. So in side of the Main Method (I was using a console app for testing) I tried the following:

```
var test = context.DeviceTests
    .Where(x => x.Env.TimeStamp == new DateTime(2018, 1, 23)).ToList();
```

Making sure that the date given to the Linq query matched exactly with one of my data points in my seed method for the database. The query returned a list of one device object that matched exactly with what I expected to see. Next I tried to get all of the dates greater than this:

```
var test = context.DeviceTests
    .Where(x => x.Env.TimeStamp >= new DateTime(2018, 1, 23)).ToList();
```

That also worked, returning me all of matching device objects in a list. So I then tried the opposite.

```
var test = context.DeviceTests
    .Where(x => x.Env.TimeStamp <= new DateTime(2018, 1, 23)).ToList();
```

Again that worked. So for sanity I checked to see if my original solution would work.

```
var test = context.DeviceTests
    .Where(x => x.Env.TimeStamp >= new DateTime(2018, 1, 23) 
    && x.Env.TimeStamp <= new DateTime(2018, 1, 26)).ToList();
```

Unsurprisingly it did not work.

So using the rubber duck method. I explained to my robot toy on my desk and it hit me. My original solution was (in English) "where timestamp is equal to or less than search date **and** timestamp is equal to or more than end date". But when I said it out loud: "where timestamp is equal to or less than search date **and where** timestamp is equal to or more than end date".

So I tried it:

```
var tests = context.DeviceTests
    .Where(x =>x.Env.TimeStamp >= new DateTime(2018, 1, 23))
    .Where(x =>x.Env.TimeStamp <= new DateTime(2018, 1, 26))
    .ToList();
```

It worked and returned a list of the objects I was looking for. I then tested it in my main project and it also worked!.

I believe that Linq-to-entities for EF non-core 6 does not like Where statements that contain logic operators.I have not yet found documentation to validate this. If I do find the documentation I will post a link here.